# How do i deal with multiple contructor arguments or class variables?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

How do I know what to load in a constructor and what to set using the set methods later on?

For example, I have a question class which most of the time will call the following vars:

```
protected $question;
protected $content;
protected $creator;
protected $date_added;
protected $id;
protected $category;
```

At the moment I have it so only the bare essentials `$id`, `$question`, and `$content` are set in the constructor so I don't start building up a huge list of constructor arguments. This however, means that when I make a new question object elsewhere, I have to set the other properties of that object straight after meaning 'setter code' getting duplicated all over the place.

Should I just pass them all into the constructor right away, do it the way I'm doing it already, or is there a better solution that I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you can have multiple constructors for any one class.

Comment: the language is PHP as noted

Comment: Ahh ok, off the top of my head I don't think overloading (multiple constructors) is possible in php. However you could use variable arguments to produce a similar effect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array as the parameter to the constructor or setter method.

Just example:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array()) {
  $this->setAttributes($attributes);
}  

public function setAttributes($attributes = array()) {
  foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $this->{$key} = $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're doing this, there's no reason to even create a class in the first place. You could simply store everything in StdClass or an assoc array.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support traditional constructor overloading (as other OO languages do). An option is to pass an array of arguments into the constructor:

```
public function __construct($params)
{

}

// calling it
$arr = array(
    'question' => 'some question',
    'content' => ' some content'
    ...
);
$q = new Question($arr);
```

Using that, you're free to pass a variable number of arguments and there is no dependency on the order of arguments. Also within the constructor, you can set defaults so if a variable is not present, use the default instead.

Comment: If you're doing this, there's no reason to even create a class in the first place. You could simply store everything in StdClass or an assoc array.

Comment: @akimsko my point was to set the properties within the constructor, not to remove the properties altogether. This is a vehicle to get the properties set in a clean way. It isn't supposed to eliminate the properties.

Comment: But it most likely will. His next step will be to store it in an array internally. Then he will assume certain properties are set in the array, or make checks every time he wants to access a property, or have to validate the entire array in the constructor. I'm just saying, this is a dangerous path to go down. And something way too many PHP developers fall prey to ;)

Comment: @akimsko I don't follow you at all, nowhere have I suggested storing an "internal array". The only array is the argument to the constructor.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Lets assume he validates the array, and assigns to properties. That's atleast halfway decent. But if this is the way to go, why would you ever use anything else but 'array $params' as the sole argument for any method/constructor you ever create?

Comment: The answer to that is the same reason in other OO languages you don't overload every constructor that you ever create. Looks like we'll have to agree to disagree on this, Best.

Answer (score 0):

A fluent interface is another solution.

```
class Foo {
  protected $question;
  protected $content;
  protected $creator;
  ...

  public function setQuestion($value) {
    $this->question = $value;
    return $this;
  }

  public function setContent($value) {
    $this->content = $value;
    return $this;
  }

  public function setCreator($value) {
    $this->creator = $value;
    return $this;
  }

  ...
}

$bar = new Foo();
$bar
  ->setQuestion('something')
  ->setContent('something else')
  ->setCreator('someone');
```

Or use inheritance...

```
class Foo {
  protected $stuff;

  public function __construct($stuff) {
    $this->stuff = $stuff;
  }

  ...
 }

class bar extends Foo {
  protected $moreStuff;

  public function __construct($stuff, $moreStuff) {
    parent::__construct($stuff);
    $this->moreStuff = $moreStuff;
  }

  ...
}
```

Or use optional parameters...

```
class Foo {
  protected $stuff;
  protected $moreStuff;

  public function __construct($stuff, $moreStuff = null) {
    $this->stuff = $stuff;
    $this->moreStuff = $moreStuff;
  }

  ...
}
```

In any case, there are many good solutions. Please dont use a single array as params or func_get_args or _*get/*_set/__call magic, unless you have a really good reason to do so, and have exhausted all other options.

Comment: A single array seems to cause the same sort of messy code somewhere along the line, but what about redreggae's answer? It seems like a god solution to me, is there any reason why not to use this? Is this what you mean by '_get/_set/__call magic'?

Comment: redreggae's is sortof ok. Atleast it will move you towards building a proper class with setters, and only allow you to set properties you actually have on the class (or at least have setters for). However, it does involve som (IMO unnecessary) reflection and checks, to find the setters. The __get, __set, __call part, was not related to any perticular answer. If you dont know what they are, you're better of not knowing ;) But as you're undoubtedly going to look them up now, here's a link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 0):

I would pass an array to the constructor with the values I want to set.

```
public function __construct(array $values = null)
{
    if (is_array($values)) {
        $this->setValues($values);
    }
}
```

Then you need a method `setValues` to dynamicly set the values.

```
public function setValues(array $values)
{
    $methods = get_class_methods($this);
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
        if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

For this to work you need setter methods for your properties like `setQuestion($value)` etc.