# How can I mention keyword arguments in php constructor?

Tags: php

I am new to `PHP OOP`.

I have this constructor

```
protected $path='default';  

function __construct($var1, $var2 ..){
        $this->var1=$var1;
        $this->var2=$var2;
    }

$obj = MyClass($var1='www')
```

I want that if I make object and don't pass any arguments then I get the object with empty values.

But if mention the properties in the constructor like above then the object should have those properties set.

Currently if I define the constructor with args and don't supply any then I get error
.

Comment: What kind of class is it? What should it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use `func_get_args()` in PHP

```
<?php
class foo
{

    private $arrParams;

    function __construct()
    {
        if (func_num_args() != 0) {
            $this->arrParams = $this->setValues(func_get_args());

        }
    }

    public function setValues($params)
    {
        return $params;
    }

    public function dispParams()
    {
        print_r($this->arrParams);
    }

    public function retVal($var)
    {
        return $this->arrParams[$var];
    }

}

$foo1 = new Foo(3, 45, 64, 34);
$foo1->dispParams();
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 64
    [3] => 34
)
```

**For getting a corresponding value from the array... You could just call**

```
 $foo1->retVal(2); // Prints you 64
```

Comment: Provided i have properties like `$a, $b , $c` in Foo . I want that all thses should work. `Foo($a='33'), Foo($b='dsds') , Foo($c='wqwq', $b='22') and Foo()` without error and with properties set as defined in constructor

Comment: That will get more complicated if you are going to pass like 10 to 15 parameters and you will be having variables like `$a,$b,$c,$d,$d.....` goes on .. which is not good. Just do like I have done i.e. created a private array variable and just then map the values using `func_get_args()`

Comment: so it means i have to get the args from constructor and then manually sets those in the porperties of object . i was thinking if its possible without manually setting it. `$this->$key = $value;`

Comment: Yeah with `func_get_args()` you don't have to need for that. All the parameters you pass are directly pushed into the array.

Comment: but i need some function to set them on properties of class. like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14937691/3147180

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare class property like this:

```
class  yourClass{

protected $path='default';  
public $var1;
public $var2;
function __construct($var1="dd", $var2='ss'){
        $this->var1=$var1;
        $this->var2=$var2;
    }

}

$obj = new yourClass();
echo "without params: ".$obj->var1.$obj->var2;

$obj2 = new yourClass("sdf","sfdsdf");
echo " with params : ".$obj2->var1.$obj2->var2;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/107675)

Comment: @user3147180: did you try this ?

Comment: i think all i wanted is that i pass avriable number of keywords arguments in constructor and constructor should should set that to the properties of class